# Url redirection issue in nginx -AmazonEc2 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, redirect, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am getting an issue.
We have created a new website for our site using angularJs and ruby on rails.I am using amazon EC2 for hosting purpose.I have used thin and nginx as webserver and application server respectively.

I have made changes in the nginx.conf file and have written redirection rules.However I am having an issue while implementing the same.

While going to TV guide from a website,the url it is showing is :-

```
http://www.abc.com/WhatsOnTV/Star_world/Boston-legal.aspx?Time=140220141300
```

It is redirecting me to:-

```
http://apps.abc.com/WhatsOnTV/Program/Boston_legal.aspx
```

Whereas it should have landed on:-

```
 abc.com/program/Boston-Legal
```

This is happening because of the the config file in which I have written the rule(which cannot be removed as we require it ):-

```
rewrite (?i)^/WhatsOnTV(.*) http://apps.abc.com/WhatsOnTV$1 permanent;
```

Also another issue I am facing is that the url encoding is different for both.In the old site the space in programs was encoded with `_` and in our current site it is encoded with `-`

My rails routes are the following:-

```
  WoiWeb::Application.routes.draw do
  get "appi/index"
  get "appi/reco"
  get "appi/auto"
  get "appi/tsm"
  get "appi/user"


  get "myaccount/index"
  post "myaccount/create"

  get "socialfeed/index"

  get "myprofile/index"

  get "discussion/home"

  get "discussion/newdiscussion"

  get "sitemap/index"

  get "privacy/index"

  get "tnc/index"

  get "corporate/index"

  get "contact/index"

  get "about/index"

  get "apps/index"

  get "videos/index"

  get "movies/index"

  get "pop_up/show"
  get "watchlistsocial/index"
  get "favourites/index"
  get "reminders/index"

  get "channels"             => "channel#index"
  get "channels/details"     => "channel#details"
  get "home"                 => "home#index"
  get "languages"            => "languages#index"
  get "genre"                => "genre#index"
  get "languages/accounts"   => "languages#accounts"
  get "programme"            => "programme#index"
  get "programme/info"       => "programme#info"
  get "search"               => "search#index"
  get "movies"               => "movies#index"
  get "videos"               => "videos#index"
  get "apps"                 => "apps#index"
  get "tv-guide"             => "tv-guide#index"
  get "tv-guide/calendar"    => "tv-guide#calendar"
  get "tv-guide/tvoperator"  => "tv-guide#tvoperator"
  get "tv-guide/accountstvoperator" => "tv-guide#accountstvoperator"
  get "pop-up/show"          => "pop-up#show"
  get "pop-up/genre"         => "pop-up#genre"
  get "pop-up/showChannelGenre" => "pop-up#showChannelGenre"
  get "pop-up/showRating"    => "pop-up#rating"
  get "pop-up/reminder"      => "pop-up#reminder"
  get "user/signin"          => "user#signin"
  get "user/signup"          => "user#signup"
  get "user/forgot-password" => "user#forgotPassword"
  get "user/popup_login"     => "user#popup_login"
  get "user/beforeaction"    => "user#beforeaction"
  get "user/watchlist"       => "user#watchlist"
  get "user/reminders"       => "user#reminders"
  get "verify/index"         => "verify#index"
  get "watchlist"            => "watchlist#index"
  get "watchlistinfo"        => "watchlist#info"
  get "movies/popover"       => "movies#popover"
  get "watchlist/calendar"   => "watchlist#calendar"
  get "ip"                   => "ip#index"
  get "actor/profile"        => "actor#profile"
  get "productions"          => "productions#index"
  get "crawler/crawlhome"    => 'crawler#crawlhome'
  get "crawler/crawlprogram" => 'crawler#crawlprogram'
  get "crawler/crawlchannel" => 'crawler#crawlchannel'
  get "crawler/crawlchannels" => 'crawler#crawlchannels'
  get "crawler/crawlactor"   => 'crawler#crawlactor'
  get "crawler/crawltvlistings"   => 'crawler#crawltvlistings'
  get "crawler/crawlmovies" => 'crawler#crawlmovies'
  get "crawler/crawlvideos" => 'crawler#crawlvideos'
  get "crawler/crawlmobileapps" => 'crawler#crawlmobileapps'

  get "videos/sitemap"     => 'videos#sitemap'
```

So I am stuck with this.Can someone please suggest me some way to tackle this.

Also want to know if it would be better just to make changes in the backend if it's a better option

Comment: I don't get how from "Start_world" is redirecting to "Boston-Legal" that's not even in your rule. It's possible that this redirect is happening at the Rails side. Can you post the pertinent Rails route?

Comment: @Rico it is taking the last bit of url and redirectly me there

Comment: Post your Rails routes...

Comment: @Rico sorry for the late response..I have updated the question.Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. Are you landing to `abc.com` or to `apps.abc.com`? In below regex its forwarding to the `abc.com`

```
rewrite (?i)^/.*/(.*?)\.aspx\? ht tp://abc.com/program/$1 permanent;
```

replace `ht tp` as `http` from above.

Comment: I am landing to apps.abc.com instead of abc.com..Will the above help me ??

Comment: I am not sure, possibly you can do this by replace `permanent` with `[R=301,L]`

Comment: will it work I mean this code you have specified without
permanent

Comment: I can't tell you as I don't know much about htaccess.